# Jquery - inArray - Check value exists or not after compare

Tags: jquery

inArray will check exact value exists or not?

from url, getting `linkTrim` = `offer3for2`

from cookie split, `offerSplit` = `?url1=/offers/offer3for2`

Need to compare and check whether `offer3for2` text exists in both `linkTrim` & `offerSplit` or not.

**Path:**

```
https://www.test.com/content/test/en/offers/offer3for2.html
```

**cookie - offerParameter**

```
%3Furl1%3D%2Foffers%2Foffer3for2%26url2%3D%2Foffers%2Ftest%26url3%3D%2Foffers%2Fadvance-purchase
```

**JS:**

```
var linkPath  = window.location.pathname;
var linkSplit = linkPath.replace(/\.\w+$/, '').split('/');
var linkTrim  = linkSplit.slice(-1).join('/');
console.log('Link name: ', linkTrim);

let offerParameter = $.cookie('offerParameter');
let offerSplit = offerParameter.split('&');

if($.inArray(linkTrim, offerSplit)){
  console.log("Name Exists");
} else { 
  console.log("Name Not Exists");
}
```

Comment: `$.inArray` looks for an exact match, not a substring. `offer3for2` is not the same as `?url1=/offers/offer3for2`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reply.. is there is any way to splice or slice array to match with path name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for an exact match, but you want to search for a substring. You can use the `.includes()` method to test if a string contains a substring. Use `.any()` to search an array for an element that matches an arbitrary test.

```js
var linkTrim = "offer3for2";
var offerSplit = ["?url1=/offers/offer3for2"];

if (offerSplit.some(s => s.includes(linkTrim))) {
  console.log("Name exists");
} else {
  console.log("Name Not Exists");
}
```